# Instal pecl_http: raphf installed but ./configure isn't seeing it

Tags: php, pecl

I'm trying to install pecl_http as an extension to php.

phpise is working fine as I'm getting the configure file out. When I go to type ./configure I get the following error message;

```
...
checking openssl/crypto.h usability... yes
checking openssl/crypto.h presence... yes
checking for openssl/crypto.h... yes
checking for gnutls support in libcurl... no
checking for ares support in libcurl... no
checking for bundled SSL CA info... /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
checking for event2/event.h... found in /usr
checking for libevent version, roughly... 2.0.19-stable
checking for ext/raphf support... no
configure: error: Please install pecl/raphf and activate extension=raphf.so in your php.ini
```

I've added the following line to my php.ini file

```
extension=raphf.so
```

I know raphf is installed and loading as I've checked it with the following php:

```
echo extension_loaded(raphf) ? "raphf loaded" : "raphf not loaded";
```

Which comes back it is loaded.

Why is ./configure not seeing raphf?

Comment: Look into the `configure` script to see what exactly and how it is checking for. Might just be a mismatching php.ini location, php binary, or it's rather looking for header files.

Answer (score 4):

In the event that anyone is still interested in how to solve this problem, I just came up with a solution. The configuration script of pecl_http looks for the module to be enabled not for the apache php module, but for the php Command Line Interface. If you run php -m, you will see that nor raphf neither propro are enabled. For the CLI to enable this modules, you must add:

```
extension=raphf.so
extension=propro.so
```

In /etc/php5/cli/php.ini as well, since that is the initalization file php CLI runs when it starts. After that, you will have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have been racking my brains on this problem over the last few months. The solution to this problem could just involve uninstalling the module. For some reason, pecl still thinks the module is installed when it really isn't.

Thus, my work around was to confirm if pecl still thinks it is installed by using `pecl list`. If it lists it, then uninstall the module with `pecl uninstall [modulename]`. Once I uninstalled it, I was finally able to install raphf.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but the solution provided by Dechcaudron has not solved the problem. Neither have the answers from here: [Ubuntu pecl install pecl_http fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892808/ubuntu-pecl-install-pecl-http-fail)

I found out that `php-config --php-binary` returns `NONE` instead of the binary of php. Because the configure script uses this command to get the php binary and then calls `$PHP_EXECUTABLE -m | $EGREP ^raphf$` it thinks `raphf` has not loaded yet. The solution was to manipulate the configure script so it uses the correct binary for php.

```
~# pecl download pecl_http
~# tar -xf pecl_http-2.5.3.tgz
~# cd pecl_http-2.5.3
~/pecl_http-2.5.3# phpize --clean
~/pecl_http-2.5.3# phpize
~/pecl_http-2.5.3# sed "s/^PHP_EXECUTABLE=.*$/PHP_EXECUTABLE=\"\/usr\/bin\/php\"/g" -i configure
~/pecl_http-2.5.3# ./configure
~/pecl_http-2.5.3# make
~/pecl_http-2.5.3# make install
```

Then add `extension=http.so` to your php.ini for apache2 and cli and your done.
**Hint:** Normally you can find the correct path for your php binary with `which php`.